# How to rewrite ado notation as general Applicative lifting, respecting evaluation order?

Tags: functional-programming, applicative, purescript, lifting

There seems to be a difference in the evaluation order of [applicative do notation](https://book.purescript.org/chapter7.html#lifting-arbitrary-functions) / `ado` vs.  applicative lifting via `<$>`/`map` on the first argument, and `<*>`/`apply` for remaining arguments.

At least, this is [what I have read](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/2435#issuecomment-261403390) so far and what is reflected in the course of the  exercise shown below. Questions:

1. Why is the evaluation order of solution 1 and 2 different (general concepts)?
2. How can  I rewrite solution 2 (*without* `ado`), respecting the preorder assertion from the test?

### Given

Exercise from the PureScript by Example book (Chapter 7) can be found [here](https://book.purescript.org/chapter7.html#exercises-2):

> 3.(Medium) Write a function `traversePreOrder :: forall a m b. Applicative m => (a -> m b) -> Tree a -> m (Tree b)` that performs a pre-order traversal of the tree. [...] Applicative do notation (ado) is the easiest way to write this function.

Algebraic data type `Tree`:

```hs
data Tree a
  = Leaf
  | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

Test expecting the traverse order `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`:

```hs
Assert.equal (1 .. 7)
          $ snd
          $ runWriter
          $ traversePreOrder (\x -> tell [ x ])
          $ Branch (Branch (leaf 3) 2 (leaf 4)) 1 (Branch (leaf 6) 5 (leaf 7))
```

<sup>Note: I am not sure, what `tell` and `runWriter` exactly do - this is a copied code block from the exercise.</sup>

For illustration - the example tree looks like this:

[image]

### What I tried

#### Solution 1: `ado` (works)

```hs
traversePreOrder :: forall a m b. Applicative m => (a -> m b) -> Tree a -> m (Tree b)
traversePreOrder f Leaf = pure Leaf
traversePreOrder f (Branch tl v tr) = ado
  ev <- f v
  etl <- traversePreOrder f tl
  etr <- traversePreOrder f tr
  in Branch etl ev etr
```

#### Solution 2: conventional lifting (does not work)

```hs
traversePreOrder :: forall a m b. Applicative m => (a -> m b) -> Tree a -> m (Tree b)
traversePreOrder f Leaf = pure Leaf
traversePreOrder f (Branch tl v tr) =
  let
    ev = f v -- I consciously tried to place this evaluation first, does not work
    etl = traversePreOrder f tl
    etr = traversePreOrder f tr
  in
    Branch <$> etl <*> ev <*> etr
```

This triggers the error:

> expected [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], got [3,2,4,1,6,5,7]

Comment: `tell` and `runWriter` would be usage of the writer monad (applicative functor?), which basically allows building a list / writing into an append-only log as an applicative effect. In short, the test checks whether your function applies the effects in the right order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```hs
> let
>   ev = f v -- I consciously tried to place this evaluation first, does not work
>   etl = traversePreOrder f tl
>   etr = traversePreOrder f tr
> in
>   Branch <$> etl <*> ev <*> etr
> ```

Source order does not matter in functional programming. You could place these `let` declarations in any order, it would work the same - they would create the same values, and these values would describe the same computation, and will form the same programs when used in the same expressions.

The "evaluation order" that actually matters here is a property of the applicative functor you're using - the order in which *applicative effects* are applied. The order is governed by the operators from the `Applicative` typeclass which you are using here, namely `<*>`: it is documented to first apply the effects from the left hand side, then the effects from the right hand side. To implement pre-order traversal, you will therefore have to write

```hs
traversePreOrder :: forall a m b. Applicative m => (a -> m b) -> Tree a -> m (Tree b)
    traversePreOrder f Leaf = pure Leaf
    traversePreOrder f (Branch tl v tr) =
      (\ev etl etr -> Branch etl ev etr) <$> f v <*> traversePreOrder f tl <*> traversePreOrder f tr
```

<sub>(Disclaimer: I don't know PureScript very well, but it looks very much like Haskell and seems to work the same here.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this works! Indeed PureScript is heavily inspired by Haskell (and in most parts equivalent from my limited experience) - I can read Haskell docs and learn something for PS.